# Spliting into lines then into variables

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, split

i have this text file below:

> 001 Bulbasaur 45 49 49 65 65 45 Grass Poison
>   002 Ivysaur 60 62 63 80 80 60 Grass Poison
>   003 Venusaur 80 82 83 100 100 80 Grass Poison
>   004 Charmander 39 52 43 60 50 65 Fire
>   005 Charmeleon 58 64 58 80 65 80 Fire

I have written this piece of code to split it into lines then into variables but it refuses to work, my apology's if i am asking this in the wrong place. (unity C# question).

```
var lines = textFile.text.Split("\n"[0]);
    allMonsters = new Monsters[lines.Length];
    List<string> lineSplit = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
        Debug.Log(lines[i]);

        lineSplit.Clear();
        lineSplit = lines[i].Split(' ').ToList ();

        int ID                  = int.Parse(lineSplit[0]);
        string Name             = lineSplit[1].ToString();
        float HP                = float.Parse(lineSplit[2]);
        float ATK            = float.Parse(lineSplit[3]);
        float DEF            = float.Parse(lineSplit[4]);
        float SPATK             = float.Parse(lineSplit[5]);
        float SpDEF             = float.Parse(lineSplit[6]);
        float speed             = float.Parse(lineSplit[7]);
        FirstType Ft        =   (FirstType)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(FirstType),lineSplit[8]);
        SecondType ST    =          (SecondType)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(SecondType),lineSplit[9]);    }
```

The code works for the first line but then on the second run of this code i get null reference to an object error, please help me.

Note, variables are assigned to so they aren't overwritten after code.

EDIT: LineSplit variable is over 1200 elements long, so i do not think unity is clearing the array properly could this be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure it is splitting the lines correctly? I would start by logging out the line it is trying to parse each time so you can see what it is dealing with directly.  I would guess at this point that its ingesting the entire file as a single line at this point.  That is what comes to my mind when you say it works for the first but not subsequent lines.  If you get more info about how the lines are being parsed in your debug log that could help us figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the lines end with `\n`? It could also contain `\r`, which can interfere with the integrity of the result when parsing like this. (It took me a long time to realize this being the error in one of my codes). I've no idea of C#, but if it's supported, try splitting using regex ("$"=end of line) or replace all "\r" by nothing.

Comment: @Raymond Tunstill can you check on witch iteration and line you get the exception?

Comment: After inspection the line split has a count of 1274 compared to a max of 10 it should have but i am unsure why.

Comment: @RoyShmuli It is after the first itteration of the first for loop

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the second iteration, but on the 4th iteration line `004 Charmander 39 52 43 60 50 65 Fire` have only 9 parameters (by split of space) and you using `lineSplit[9]`, so there you will get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I think this is probably part of the problem but not all of it.  You should probably have a placeholder value you can check for in the file when no secondary type is provided. For example "004 Charmander 39 52 43 60 50 65 Fire NULL".  Then on your ST if it is NULL you know populate it as needed.

Comment: If you could I think showing the 1200 characters you are getting (or at least a snipper of how it starts and ends) might also be useful (you may need to debug log them).  It will give you as well as us a chance to spot clues about the what/how/why of where the extra data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

When working with text files, linefeed often comes along with carriage return.
Try

```
var lines = textFile.text.Split(new string[]{"\r\n"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

in the first line.